# How to determine UPSERT operation with INSERT .. ON CONFLICT?

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I would like to be able to tell which operation (`INSERT` or `UPDATE`) took place after execution of an `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT`. Perhaps as a subquery as part of the `RETURNING` clause?

It seems there was a [similar request about a month ago](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAM3SWZT3X4zsKQwoAfe59afay+MWLLpQXtMDOVchBJfv+iqrNg@mail.gmail.com) and Peter Geoghegan responded that it might be possible with a hack of somekind. If anyone has any idea, I would love to hear it right about now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resorted to the following pseudo-code. I'm in a `plpgsql` function so I could use variables. But I think I could potentially wrap it up into a CTE too.

1. `DECLARE var INT;`
2. `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING 1 INTO var;`
3. `PERFORM ... WHERE var IS NOT NULL;` (var is 1 if INSERT, NULL if update)
4. `UPDATE ...` (what I wanted to do on conflict in step 2)

Basically always execute the update, defeating the purpose of the new UPSERT function, but there doesn't seem to be an official way so far.

Answer (score 1):

I am using following approach:

```
insert into users (created_at, updated_at, email)
values (now(), now(), 'user@example.com')
on conflict (email) 
do update set updated_at = now()
returning users.*, (created_at = updated_at) as new_user_created
```

After insert new_user_created will be true, and after update it will be false.
I am not sure how it will work inside transaction in which user is first created and then updated - probably now() will return exactly same value in each call.

Answer (score 1):

Add column to your table to determine. For example.. 'I' means Insert, 'U' menas Update  to use.

`ALTER TABLE foo
ADD COLUMN lastoperation text;`

`INSERT INTO foo (c1,c2,...,lastoperation)
 values (?,?,.... 'I')
ON CONFLICT (<your ndx or keys>) 
 DO UPDATE SET
    lastoperation='U' returning lastoperation;`

If operation is INSERT , lastoperation value will be 'I', other way 'U'. You can use lastoperation column value..